# pd DataFrame, need to add columns, parsing text string date_time into pandas year, dayOfWeek, etc in one pass

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sqlite, datetime, to-date

**Need Statement**: I have performed a cursor.fetchall Select from a SQLite database, returning 'id' and 'date_time', the later of which is text. I want to create additional columns using pd.to_date of year, dayOfWeek, dayOfYear, hourOfDay

**Issue:** Following the example of a [no-loop column add and population approach](http://%20%20https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/intro_tutorials/05_add_columns.html), I've tried multiple call combinations, none of which work.

I first tested a series of calls to confirm I could split the test date correctly;

```
sr = pd.Series(['2015-02-08 20:00:00']) 
sr = pd.to_datetime(sr) 

#Year: Series.dt.year The year of the datetime
#Day of week: Series.dt.dayofweek The day of the week with Monday=0, Sunday=6 
#Day of year: Series.dt.dayofyear The ordinal day of the year
#Hour: Series.dt.hour The hours of the datetime

print(sr)
print(sr.dt.year )
print(sr.dt.dayofweek )
print(sr.dt.dayofyear )
print(sr.dt.hour )
```

Everything came out as expected;

> 0   2015-02-08 20:00:00
> dtype: datetime64[ns]
> 0    2015
> dtype: int64
> 0    6
> dtype: int64
> 0    39
> dtype: int64
> 0    20
> dtype: int64

The code I've tried works perfectly through the lines below, returning 105,861 rows x 2 columns;

```
def splitDateTime():
    try:
            sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect('TestElecConsump.db')
            cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
            print("Connected to SQLite")
    
            sqlite_select_query = """SELECT id, date_time from WeatherRecord;"""
            cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query)
            records = cursor.fetchall()
            
            print("Total rows are:  ", len(records))
            print("Printing first row:", records[0])
            
            splitDatepd = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=['id','date_time']) 
            print("Dataframe shape:", splitDatepd.shape)
            print("Dataframe : " , splitDatepd, sep='\n')
        
            print ('records: ' + str(type(records)))
            print ('splitDatepd: ' + str(type(splitDatepd)))
```

However, the next lines execute with no output whatsoever;

```
#Add new column of Pandas datetime year

splitDatepd["pd-datetime"] = splitDatepd.to-datetime["date_time"].dt.year

print("Dataframe shape:", splitDatepd.shape)
print("Dataframe : " , splitDatepd, sep='\n')
```

So I decided to simplfy matters by repeated the above by leaving off the .year parsing;

```
splitDatepd["pd-datetime"] = splitDatepd.to-datetime["date_time"]
```

Still there was no change to splitDatepd.

When the def finalizes and returns the dataframe, a printout of it looks exactly like the original dataframe from the Select statement.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with the `pd.to_datetime` function in a single column, for example:

`splitDatepd["pd_datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(splitDatepd["date_time"])`

PS: Remember that functions names use underscode, I mean, it is `pd.to_datetime` not `pd.to-datetime`.

Comment: That worked, and allowed me to add ".dt.year" to the end of that expression, which returned the year, so I can immediately populate the year, day of week, etc. ty!